# How to run a single php file on Google cloud?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to create php file that saves information in the database. This information is provided in JSON format using POST url.

If it were PhpMyAdmin, we would have done it as below:

```
<?php
   $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
   if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
       echo "Error connecting to database";
   }else{
       $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
       $obj = json_decode($json);
       $x = $obj->{'x'};
       $y = $obj->{'y'};
       $z = $obj->{'z'};

       $query = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('$x', '$y', '$z')";
       $result = $con->query($query);
       if(!$result){
            die("Data base error");
       }
   }
```

To run above php file, we get url and if you pass data to that url, desired operation is performed. The URL will be something like this and we can access it from anywhere:

"http://****server_name*****/****file_name****.php"

Now, I want to do the same thing using Google Cloud. I have created database in Cloud SQL. But, I am not getting where to create PHP file, how to access database in this PHP file and what will be the URL.

Can someone please help as I am new to Google Cloud. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to write a [Google App Engine (GAE) PHP](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/) app for it and deploy/run it on GAE (GAE takes care of all the infra for you). Simpler IMHO plus potentially free (depending on your app usage).

Another option is to use a [Google Compute Engine (GCE) VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) and manage/run your app (and all required infra) yourself.

Both GAE and GCE are Google Cloud products.

Comment: Can you please provide some code, that would be really helpful. I have already gone through the documentation but couldn't understand and figure out.

Comment: Not really, I'm using python, not PHP. Check the tutorials, most of them have code examples on github.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your code in GAE without much trouble.

You can simply define an `app.yaml` in your project folder and deploy to the GAE.

In your `app.yaml` you can define your connection details.

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: index.php

# [START env]
env_variables:
  # Replace project, instance, database, user and password with the values obtained
  # when configuring your Cloud SQL instance.
  MYSQL_DSN: mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME;dbname=DATABASE
  MYSQL_USER: root
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: ''
# [END env]
```

You can define the connection details on the code itself( but don't ;) ) or define in the `app.yaml` as in above and call the values in your code as `getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD');`

Docs on using Google Cloud SQL on GAE Standard env [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/)

( I suggest you using the [Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) rather the [Standard  Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/about-the-standard-environment), which does not need you to do much work. 
Here's a small slide set which I did for a session on [getting started on GAE Flexible env with Php](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1sIKIccngWuJ_tgMsjTj-uzTb3drAl0d93g3iFhK6py8/edit#slide=id.g150bdf59b1_0_297) )